# MySQL JDBC Fail calculating row number

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have this select that works every time running in workbench but fails sometimes for the same arguments over jdbc. The problem is that sometimes, over JDBC, 'pos' value returns null. I Think that, for some reason, the @p as not started, but dont know how to fix.

```
SELECT t1.wId, t1.twId, t1.name, t1.timeout, t1.pos
FROM (
SELECT w.id AS wId, tw2.id AS twId, w.name AS name, tw2.timeout AS             timeout, @p:=@p+1 AS pos
FROM timeout_workqueue tw1
INNER JOIN timeout_workqueue tw2
ON tw1.workqueue_id = tw2.workqueue_id
INNER JOIN workqueue w
ON tw1.workqueue_id = w.id
WHERE tw1.id = ?
ORDER BY tw2.id) t1, (SELECT @p:=1) c
WHERE t1.twId = ?;
```

The whole Java Code Are:

```
public TimeoutWorkqueueView getTimeoutWorkqueueView(Integer id) {

    String sql = "SELECT t1.wId, t1.twId, t1.name, t1.timeout, t1.pos"
            + " FROM ("
            + " SELECT w.id AS wId, tw2.id AS twId, w.name AS name, tw2.timeout AS timeout, @p:=@p+1 AS pos"
            + " FROM timeout_workqueue tw1"
            + " INNER JOIN timeout_workqueue tw2"
            + " ON tw1.workqueue_id = tw2.workqueue_id"
            + " INNER JOIN workqueue w"
            + " ON tw1.workqueue_id = w.id"
            + " WHERE tw1.id = ?"
            + " ORDER BY tw2.id) t1, (SELECT @p:=1) c"
            + " WHERE t1.twId = ?";

    return (TimeoutWorkqueueView) getJdbcTemplate().queryForObject(sql, new BeanPropertyRowMapper(TimeoutWorkqueueView.class), id, id);

}
```

Comment: and what is the actual java code ?

Comment: @maciej-cygan posted.

Comment: and where do you set the parameter '@p' ?

Comment: (SELECT @p:=1), but sometimes the pos column returns with null value over jdbc.

Comment: But this is a rather weird way of setting the parameter tbh. The whole point of having a parameter is to set it somewhere else down the line. If you already know what the parameter value is why not just set it at beginning. Can this param value change ? and if so how does it change ?

Comment: This will always be started as 1. I make that way because is the one i found for count row number.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the problem i can see here (please verify) is that you think you are running the query with parameter set to 1 to begin with.

However if you set @p = 1 -> this  @p:=@p+1 will not evaluate to 1 any more.

Also assuming you have 20 rows, you run this query 20 times but on the last run it will return null because pos will be 21 and this does not exists.

Comment: The problem is not with sequence calls. I always set @p to 1 on every call (SELECT @p:=1), and this works fine in mysql workbanch for any number of calls. 
But somehow, when calling over jdbc, looks like sometimes the @p as not started, so the pos column result as null.

Comment: but workbench works different to java - just because something works with workbench does not mean it will work in Java - I would start by modifying your SQL call :)

Comment: @GAP any luck with this ?

Comment: I  dont found the problem, so i just change the implementation. Thanks for the help man.